# Unable to create buckets in GCP account. Error getting access token for service account: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am trying to run my project locally. I have a service account credentials in-placed in my project. I have setup my gcloud sdk credentials. The configuration looks right to me. But i   am still getting `unable to get access token for service account. Unexpected end of file`

`ImplementationAck999Service - Critical Service Failure! Reason: Unable to create Bucket for 999 transactions. Reason: Error getting access token for service account: Unexpected end of file from server`

[image: Error while creating buckets]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Are you following any tutorial that will help to replicate this error?

Comment: @vitooh i am working on private repo. Can you tell me what can be the possible cause for the error.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't see similar issue yet, i thought that maybe it be possible to replicate and do some analyzes

Comment: Thanks @vitooh there might be some issues in my local environment. Figuring it out.

Comment: Are you sure about your credential path?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i am not sure. I just started working with GCP for the project. Can you tell me how it should be or direct me to some articles.

Comment: Are you using a service account key file? If so, how are you load it into your configuration? Can you share how did you set up your gcloud related environment?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i am using service account key file. I followed these instructions
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install

Comment: Ok. Can you run these 2 commands and paste the result in your questions? `gcloud config list` and `gcloud info`